# How to use Bit flags in mysql

Tags: mysql, bitflags

I am using binary bits flags in a mysql to determine the role of a person. The person can be either `faculty`, `instructor` or `both`. Each academy has one or more unique faculty person (one-to-many relation). Also each academy has an instructor person. An instructor person can belong to one or more academy. The table `person` stores the basic data(name, email, etc.) of that specific individual. In order to determine the role I have partially created a `person_role` table but not sure what fields or their type are needed for the use of bit flags?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `academy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `academy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `person_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `person_email` varchar(50) default NULL, 
 `person_phone` varchar(15) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `academy_id` FOREIGN KEY (`academy_id`) REFERENCES `academy` (`academy_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person_role` (
  `contact` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `instructor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another bit field on the `person_role` table called `faculty`. That way you'll be able to satisfy:

> The person can be either faculty, instructor or both.

Since there is an "one to one" relation between a person and its role, you could move the `instructor` and `faculty` bit fields on the `person` table and drop the `person_role` table.